# Remove frame from background

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, semantic-segmentation

I am having 400 images that look like the following:

[image]

I would like to remove the frame and only get the image in the middle:

[image]

I tried the MODNet model `modnet_photographic_portrait_matting`. However, I get:

[image]

As you can see the model selects the person, BUT not the sticker itself.

I would only like to get the image without the frame.

Any suggestions how to tackle this problem?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Hello, I woudn't try to apply a machine learning model to this problem. I'd rather use color detection (background seems black and there is a white frame around the sticker). Or simply rectangle shape detection with a library such as openCV. To then sort the rectangles try using x, y coordinates if the sticker is always approximately as the same spot in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MODNet, based on the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.11961.pdf), is a network that removes the background entirely just as if the person is standing in front of a green screen. And I assume that is why you are left only with the player and not the rest of the sticker.

I think you would find more use in a Region Proposal Network, such as that used in [Faster R-CNN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01497.pdf) (sec. 3.1).

Here is an [example](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/5e56575e688a85a3bc9dc3c97934dd864b65ce47/torchvision/models/detection/rpn.py#L88-L367) of the PyTorch (torchvision) implementation of such a network. Notice how the network outputs `boxes` (in the `forward()` method) which is a tuple `(x1, y1, x2, y2)`. From these four coordinates, you can get the four corners of the player sticker and crop it with a simple function.